# Can't commit a delete using git-svn: Your file or directory is probably out of date

Tags: git, git-svn

I've been looking over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629048/git-svn-dcommit-error-restart-the-commit) post, but still can't figure out how to solve my particular issue.

I'm using git-svn locally against a svn repository.  I usually do the following:

1. git svn rebase (to get the latest from the repo).
2. git checkout local-dev
3. git merge master (to merge this into my local branch)
4. make changes, committing locally as I go
5. git checkout master
6. git merge local-dev
7. git svn dcommit (to sent it all back upstream)

Usually works fine, until I tried to commit my latest batch from the merged master back to the repository:

> $ git svn dcommit
>
> Committing to http://mysvnrepository    ...
>          D       PROJECT/Content/js/dp/jquery-1.3.2.js
>
> Merge conflict during commit: Your file or directory 'PROJECT/Content/js/dp' is probably 
>   out-of-date: resource out of date; try updating at C:\Program Files\Git/ libexec/git-core/git-svn line 508

I deleted this "/dp" folder sometime in my operations and git appeared to handle everything fine, but now it won't send to to svn.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone was kind enough to help me in an irc channel.  I ended up having to do my "git merge local-dev --squash" and that managed to help it out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you are getting the conflict, but my usual tactic in this situation is to do `svn rebase` again.