# Git - revert committed changes from local repository

Tags: git, push, commit, reset, revert

I have committed a lot of changes into my local repository but I want to push only few of them. Is it possible? I have a list (before push) with all my changes, but I need to push only few. I would like to revert all this changes from my local repostitory. I created patches with only changes I want to push but now I cannot remove changes from my local repo. 
I tried to use `git reset hard` but it does not work as I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you push only some of your local git commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604399/how-do-you-push-only-some-of-your-local-git-commits)

Comment: Also related: [git - pushing specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit)

Comment: @sigy I think OP's problem is different since they also want to change their local history

Comment: @Dunno As I understood it OP only wants to revert to then be able to push, but you might be right. Maybe OP can clarify?

Comment: Yes, I want to push only few changes from my local repo. Not everything, so the link you gave can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, *really* just want to delete unwanted commits, then do

```
git rebase -i <sha_of_commit_before_those_that_are_unwanted>
```

and then delete lines with commits you want to get rid of.

**However**, bear in mind that those commit *will* disappear and getting them back might not be possible. Maybe push those commits to a temporary remote branch first, or make a local branch with them?

Now that you've gotten rid of your commits, you can do a simple `git push origin branch`

Comment: Well, if I create a temporary branch and commit changes from local repo to this branch than it should resolve my problem, am I right? It is a safe way I think.

Comment: @allocer yes, making a local branch will also preserve your commits. I just prefer pushing to remote for additional safety

Comment: I've created new local branch, push there all my changes, back to main branch and open Push window. The local changes are still there like before. How to resolve this?