# Importing an another Repos in an existing Repos in Azure Devops

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have 3 APIs and 1 MVC in my project. I want to clone all of them from TFS into Azure Repos along with history. I do that by cloning from TFS to local repository, then pushing local repository to Git repository and finally importing that Git repository into Azure Repos.

But when I start cloning, it takes lot of time because size is too large when all of them combined.

So I imported the MVC first into a Azure Repos, but now I also want to add all other 3 APIs into same Azure Repos along with history.

Is it possible to add multiple Git repositories into a single Azure Repos(along with history)?

Comment: Are you talking about TFVC repos, or Git repos? Please clarify your question by providing details and using precise terminology.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can not import multiple Git repositories into a single Azure Repos. You could combine the repos into one repo, and push it. If not all commits are necessary, you could push only some of your local git commits: [how do you push only some of your local git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604399/how-do-you-push-only-some-of-your-local-git-commits/28795645)

```
$ git push origin master~3:master
```